# How to make Discord Bot make sure your pinging someone in a command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make the bot say the name of someone I pinged and give that person a role. Right now, if you don't ping someone, the whole bot breaks.

Here is my code:

```js
const taggedUser0 = msg.mentions.members.first();
if (!args.length) {
  msg.author.send(`You didn't ping, ${msg.author}!`);
  msg.delete(); // Deletes command
} else if (msg.member.roles.holds(role)) {
    // checks if the person mentioned already has a role
    return;
  } else {
    taggedUser0.roles.add(role); // adds role
  }
  msg.author.send(`${taggedUser0}.`);
  msg.delete(); // Deletes command
}
```

Comment: What does "my whole bot breaks" mean. Did you get an error?

Comment: Yes, I get an error.

Comment: Could we see the error? I believe the problem is that you should just be writing `else` instead of `else if ()`. Also, `.holds()` is not a function. Use `.has()`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I see a few problems with your code:

---

First of all, `else if()` will always return an error.

```js
if (false) console.log(false)
else if () console.log(true) // wrong usage
```

```js
if (false) console.log(false)
else console.log(true) // correct usage
```

---

Second of all, you should switch this `if` statement:

```js
if (!args.length)

// to:

if (!taggedUser0)
```

Someone could have added an `arg` and still not have mentioned anyone.

---

Third of all, `GuildMember.roles` returns a `Manager`, not a `Collection`, so make sure you pass through the `cache` property:

```js
taggedUser0.roles.cache.holds()
```

Also, `Collection.holds()` is not a function. Instead, use `Collection.has()` (and make sure the passed parameter is the role ID, not the role object):

```js
taggedUser0.roles.cache.has('ID Here');
```

---

Lastly, to ping someone, you should use this format:

```js
message.channel.send(`<@${taggedUser0.id}>`);
```